# Return to Current Culture when clicking any button in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, uiculture

All works fine when select any of the language in my login page through Corporation page but when I click any button in Corporation Page it returns in 
Default language(English).I want to maintain it in the language I chose

Please help.

> **Corporation.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


          if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Session["language"] != null)
                {
                    string language = Session["language"].ToString();
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

                }
                string Flag = Session["Flag"].ToString();
                if (Flag == "Y")
                {
                    Session["Flag"] = "N";
                    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

                }
                Session["Flag"] = "Y";
           }
       }
```

> **Login.aspx**

```
  <div>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLang" runat="server"AutoPostBack="True"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLang_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en-US"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="French" Value="fr-FR"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="Spanish" Value="es-ES"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Text="Chinese" Value="zh-SG"></asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
          </div>
```

> **Login.aspx.cs**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {
        if (Session["language"] != null)
                {
                    ddlLang.SelectedValue = Session["language"].ToString();
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture                                  (ddlLang.SelectedValue);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLang.SelectedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture                        (ddlLang.SelectedValue);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLang.SelectedValue);
                }
               Session["Flag"] = "Y";
     }
   }





protected void ddlLang_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlLang.SelectedValue == "fr-FR")
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                Session["language"] = ddlLang.SelectedValue;
                Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
            }
            if (ddlLang.SelectedValue == "zh-SG")
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("zh-SG");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-SG");
                Session["language"] = ddlLang.SelectedValue;
                Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
            }
            if (ddlLang.SelectedValue == "es-ES")
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                Session["language"] = ddlLang.SelectedValue;
                Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                Session["language"] = ddlLang.SelectedValue;
                Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its a simple mistake

**if (!IsPostBack)** in Corporation.aspx.cs will be executed only on first load.
So basically all the settings are done only on the first load.

After you hit some button on the page there will be a postback fired which will be do a Page_Load. But this time around since its a postback your language code is not executed...